# How would i index this json response to access this specific section

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have provided an example of what the JSON looks like. I am trying to print each drivers information separately but can only print the key "Drivers".

```
{
    "MRData": {
        "xmlns": "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4",
        "series": "f1",
        "url": "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/drivers.json",
        "limit": "30",
        "offset": "0",
        "total": "21",
        "DriverTable": {
            "season": "2021",
            "Drivers": [
                {
                    "driverId": "alonso",
                    "permanentNumber": "14",
                    "code": "ALO",
                    "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Alonso",
                    "givenName": "Fernando",
                    "familyName": "Alonso",
                    "dateOfBirth": "1981-07-29",
                    "nationality": "Spanish"
                },
                {
                    "driverId": "bottas",
                    "permanentNumber": "77",
                    "code": "BOT",
                    "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valtteri_Bottas",
                    "givenName": "Valtteri",
                    "familyName": "Bottas",
                    "dateOfBirth": "1989-08-28",
                    "nationality": "Finnish"
                 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a snippet of the piece of code dealing with the json

```py
print("The drivers for the current season are : \n\n")
            succeeded = False
            api_url = r"http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/drivers.json?"
            response = requests.get(api_url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                response_json = json.loads(response.content)
                #for items in response_json:
                for (k,v) in response_json.items():
                    for (i,j) in v.items():
                        for data in j:
                      
                           drivers = '' 
                           drivers += data  
                   
                    
                           #print("Key:",i,"value :", j)
                print(drivers)
```

Comment: get the list of drivers from the dict `drivers = json['MRData']['DriverTable']['Drivers']` and then iterate it using a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this JSON object is named `json`, this will print out each driver:

```
drivers = json["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]
for driver in drivers:
    print(driver)
```

Comment: Thank you will give it a go appreciate it mate